# Uploading dump file to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am totally new to postgresql and i have database as dump file on postgresql which i need to restore/upload it back.. i didnt dumped the file its already available online. I read the documentation of restore command on postgresql but it didnt work w me and i am not sure from the steps that I should follow to successfully upload it!! Please if anyone has an idea or could at least refer me to a really good resources for how to do it I will really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Usually its as simple as:

```
psql dbname < infile
```

or if it's a custom-format dump:

```
pg_restore --dbname mydb infile
```

Comment: So I dont have to creat a new DB cuz that what I did first and then I typed that command but nothing happened!!

Comment: Well, help me help you. What do you mean by "nothing happened"? Did you get an error of some type?  Did you see any text scroll by? Anything? What operating system are you using?

Comment: thanks for helping me... I am using mac, so what I did is the following:
1. create a new database called ex new 
2. run SQL shell (psql)
3. type psql new < file.dump
and there is no error, and when I checked back the new db there was no tables!! 
I am not sure what I did is right?

Comment: No no... Don't do step number 2. Just run step 3 from the command prompt.

Comment: oh I see so now I get an error "syntax error at or near "psql""; I tried to use psql --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on dbname < infile but still getting the same error

Comment: At the command prompt, without running psql first, type the line in my original answer.

Comment: its not working!! it threw error "command not found"!! so I was wondering if I can actually "restore" a file with extension (.dump) to postgresql; cuz even if by clicking on the db and choose restore option it doesnt show me the "file.dump". another thing is the file is too large (3.5 GB) !! please any thoughts??

Comment: Well 3.5GB is not all that large. I don't understand why it said "comment not found." In your earlier comment, you said that, as step 2, you run psql. When you type what I suggested, all you are doing is running psql with some command line arguments.

Comment: You said "click" so I assume you're on Windows? Oh! Are you running some graphical version os psql? If so, open a DOS window. Make sure psql is on the PATH so you can run it (to test, in the DOS window type psql and see if it runs. "Command not found" indicates that its not in the PATH. Anyhow, once that works, In that DOS window, type what I suggested.

Comment: Or, if you want to use the graphical program, and it won't let you chose the file that ends in .dump, rename it and try again.

Comment: Ok I thought I have to share how I was able to restore the dump data... so  I used (\i path/file.dump) in psql and hola!! all the data was in my db!!  thanks again guys for helping me :)